# Content Porter generating SQL connection error

Tags: content-porter-2009

I am getting below error while I am trying to content porter from my DEVtridion to TEST tridion.

```
Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-230-1).
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Error Code:
0x8004033F (-2147220673)

Call stack:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader,RunBehavior,String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,Boolean)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String,DbAsyncResult)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,RunBehavior,Boolean,String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior,String)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior)
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation,CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation,CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.RepositoryDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IRepositoryDataMapper.FindBlueprintConflicts(TcmUri,IEnumerable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.AssertBlueprintConflicts()
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Update(UserContext,String)
XMLState.Save
Publication.Save
```

If I see content portar logs, I can find these:

```
<tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="true">
        <![CDATA[Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]]>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="8004033F" Cause="false">
        <![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS".]]>
        <tcm:Token>EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
```

What could be the reason, why my content portar is not able to get sql connection of my TEST server, however same package is going perfectly on my LIVE Tridion.

Comment: What do you mean by DevTridion to Test Tridion? I guess you must be using the Content Porter Client installed on your personal machine and from there you are connecting; if it is otherwise, kindly clarify.

Comment: Yes...connecting from client only...DEV Tridion is my develpoment Tridion and Test Tridion is where I need to port my content from DEV

Comment: My guess is that Content Porter has nothing to do with it. Have you tried to update publication tcm:0-230-1 on your Test Tridion environment directly?

Comment: Is your Tridion CM and DB are on the same server machine or different machines? Also, are the Dev and Test servers (both CM and DB) are in same network domain or in different domain?
Moreover, is it possible for you to log in to the Test Server CM machine and try running the Content Porter client from there and see if it works

Comment: @Quirijn, I am able to add/delete/update on my tcm:0-230-1, strangly same pacakge is working fine for LIVE

Comment: @PankajGaur, Yes my both DEV and TEST servers CM DB are in same server and same domain/network.

Comment: Have you made sure your database is properly maintained, i.e. indexes and statistics up to date and transaction log truncated regularly? Timeouts are usually caused by a lack of database maintenance (and dev servers usually do not get maintained properly ;o).

Comment: @Manoj What I meant was: can you update the publication itself, by opening its properties, changing something and saving it again? I know that in some complex blueprints, timeouts may occur when a publication is modified.

Comment: @Quirijn, just tested what you suggested all looks good...one thing having content porter different version on TEST and DEV can cause this issue?

Comment: No idea, my database connection in Tridion.ContentManager.config was not properly mapped, I did the changes and also did reindexing....all good now

Comment: Manoj; thanks for accepting the answer. Can you please add what actually have resolved your issue from various options provided so that it will help the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following could be the reason:

1. Health of your DB (or few tables in concern) is very low - Check the health of your Test DB by running DBCC commands and other maintenance script as mentioned in the SDL Tridion Manual for DB maintenance
2. Ports for your DB are not open - Ensure by looking at the storage config/SDL Tridion Configuration manager, what is the actual DB id is and what is the port assigned to it. If it is different than the one assigned to the Dev DB, then ensure that it is open
3. There may be issue with your SQL Server Network Configuration - Either you can compare the SQL Server Network Configuration by using SQL Server Configuration Manager for DEV DB and Test DB or you may seek help by reviewing through your DBA. Additionally, you may try running your Content Porter on the Test Server itself to check whether it works in this mode.

Comment: what about <![CDATA[A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS".]]>

Comment: I would not recommend, but if possible, try executing the EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS stored procedure directly on the SQL Query Editor on the DB server with parameters for your scenario and few other scenarios and see if it gives you errors for all of them or only for your specific scenario...then check the DB logs or error that is presented on the SQL Query Editor, I hope that might give your more information to go forward in this issue

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you configure these settings (absolutely necessary and from the manual):

**2.4.2 Changing the timeout value for transactions**

Content Porter allows users to perform a transactional import that Content Porter can roll back if it fails. As a Content Porter import can often take longer than the default system timeout setting of 30 minutes. it is recommended to change the default timeout to provide sufficient time for transactional import.

**Context**

￼Changing the timeout depends on your installed versions of Content Manager:

- On a machine which is running Content Manager Server version 2009
  SP1, Content Porter uses the COM+ transaction timeout, as configured
  in Windows Component Services, to detect if a transaction times out.
  This timeout setting is set to 1800 seconds (30 minutes) by default.
- On a machine which is running Content Manager Server version 2011
  SP1, Content Porter uses .NET transactions as configured in the .NET
  Framework. This timeout setting is set to 10 minutes by default.

On a machine which is running Content Manager Server version 2011 SP1, change the .NET system transaction as follows:

a. Navigate to your %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework \v4.0.30319\Config folder.

b. Open machine.config in a text editor.

c. Add the following section to set the maxTimeout to 1 hour:

```
<configuration>
 <system.transactions>
   <machineSettings maxTimeout="01:00:00" />
 </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

d. Modify the System.Transactions section by setting the allowExeDefinition attribute (from MachineOnly) to MachineToApplication:

```
    <sectionGroup name="system.transactions" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.TransactionsSectionGroup,
 System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null">
   <section name="defaultSettings" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.DefaultSettingsSection,
 System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="machineSettings" type="System.Transactions.Configuration.MachineSettingsSection,
 System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null"
 allowDefinition="MachineOnly" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
</sectionGroup>
```

e. Reboot the server to apply changes.