# Unable to save Multimedia Component

Tags: 2013, multimedia

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 and while saving Multimedia component I am getting the following error:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT".EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

This is normally a database maintenance issue.

The most important thing is to ensure that the `sp_updatestats` stored procedure is being run regularly (I have seen this being done 6 times per day on high volume systems).

There is an excellent SDL Tridion World article by Julian on [Maintaining SDL Tridion Databases](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/MaintainingSDLTridiondatabases.aspx) too.

Answer (score 5):

Unless, the multimedia that you are trying to upload is huge in size, You may want to check on the health of your DB.

You may want to refer these questions:

[Timeout in the TridionUploadAssembly](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/116/timeout-in-the-tridionuploadassembly)

[Content Porter generating SQL connection error](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/content-porter-generating-sql-connection-error)